# Wiring a hot tub pump

Tags: wiring

What gauge wire should I use to run 8 feet from a 13 amp pump to the control box . The wire it came with is 14 ga. But only 4 feet. Could I splice it?

Comment: If the wire can be replaced, buying ten feet of 14/3 would be the best solution (and a cheap one at that).

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, you could replace the wire entirely and avoid splices but splicing it is an option as long as you have a junction box to make the joints in. Wire nutting and taping the conductors is not acceptable to the Code.

14 AWG wire is rated for 15 amp circuits so it has the ampacity to supply your hot tub pump. The heater on the hot tub is going to have to be on a separate circuit from the pump.

Comment: ArchonOSX is correct all splices must be in a box if outside it will need to be listed for wet location, much cheaper to replace the short wire with one without a splice.